# normalized dual activation function for neural tangent kernel

Tags: neural-networks, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, activation-function

Let $\phi$ be an activation function. In this [lecture note](https://web.mit.edu/modernml/course/lectures/MLClassLecture6.pdf), The author assumes that the dual activation function, denoted as $\check{\phi}$ is normalized such that $\check{\phi}(1)=1$. How can it be possible?
Since
\begin{equation}
\check{\phi}(\xi) = \mathbb{E}_{(u,v) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\boldsymbol{\Lambda})} [\phi(u)\phi(v)] \quad\text{where}~\boldsymbol{\Lambda} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \xi \\
\xi & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Based on this definition, $\check{\phi}(1)$ is already determined, and there is no way to make it equal to 1. You may need to take a glance on the previous notes provided [here](https://web.mit.edu/modernml/course/).